# Apache Zeppelin - Syntax highlight disappears after restart a notebook

Tags: syntax-highlighting, apache-zeppelin

Whenever I close and reopen a Zeppelin notebook, the syntax highlight disappears. Only when I create a new notebook, does the syntax highlighting work.

Is there any way to fix this problem correctly?

The version of Zeppelin is 0.7.3.

Comment: Which version do you use ?

Comment: The version is 0.7.3.